# Payout for pairing teams

Tags: probability

I'm reading a book with chances and probability.
The book has the following problem:
"The draw for the fifth round of the FA Cup is about to be made.  There are 16 teams, leading to eight matches.  Your task is to pair the teams off, in an attempt to guess as many as possible off the actual matches in the real Cup draw.  You are not asked which teams will be drawn at home, just which pairs will be selected.  I am prepared to pay you $1.50 for each correct guess; how much would you be prepared to offer for the right to make the eight guesses?"
(What is the minimum fair entrance fee?)

I would like pointers to solve this by using ordinary combinatorics, if possible.  (Author uses the idea: sum of the averages is the averages of the sum, which it might be faster, but I would be jumping to an easy way of solving this without first analyzing/understand/adopt it).

I have tried the following:
First Match arrangements (16x15)=240
Second Match arrangements (14x13)=182
Third Match arrangements (12x11)=132
Fourth Match arrangements (10x9)=90
Fifth Match arrangements (8x7)=56
Sixth Match arrangements (6x5)=30
Seventh Match arrangemets (4x3)=12
Eighth Match arrangements (2x1)=2
So I get 744 possible arrangements.

I'm starting to question my above approach because on the Eighth Match arrangements, I have 2 possible ways, when intuitively I know there is only one way (it is the last matching pair), so I know I'm missing something but cannot point it down.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It happens medium often that the distribution is unpleasant to get at but  expectation is accessible.

Comment: I understand expectations are easier.  Am I trying to solve this in a very hard way?

Comment: I don't have time to write out the distribution, can push it through for $8$, in an ugly Inclusion/Exclusion way. The expectation is, by contrast, quite easy.

Comment: @André, if needed, you can simplify it, just enough to explain and I can take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $8$ guesses. Let $X_{i}:=1$ if the $i$-th guess is correct and
$X_{i}:=0$ otherwise.

Then $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{i}\right]=P\left\{ X_{i}=1\right\} =\dfrac{1}{15}$
and $\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}+\cdots+X_{8}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]+\cdots+\mathbb{E}\left[X_{8}\right]=\dfrac{8}{15}$.

This gives an expected value of $\dfrac{8}{15}\times\$1.50=\$0.80$

Comment: This, counts the arrangements, but what about the estimated number of correct match diagnostics?

Comment: @user4140 You are right, I made an edit.

Comment: @drhab, you're right, you got the solution using expected values, but is there a way to solve this by analyzing its permutations or combinations?

Comment: @CAGT If there is indeed such a way, then it is quite a nasty way, I think. To get some hold on it first try to solve it for a smaller number of teams ($4$, $6$, $8$). However, I have not the courage to make any promises.

Comment: @drhab, thanks, I will do the excercise for smaller teams and see if I can build from there.